# $E[(Y_1-f(x))^2] \leq E[(Y_2-Y_1)^2]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes, martingales

*Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous bounded function, $(X_k)_k$ a sequence of i.i.d random variables such that $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x+y)dP_{X_1}(y).$$
Let $x \in \mathbb{R},Y_k=f\left(x+\sum_{q=1}^kX_q\right),\mathcal{F}_k=\sigma(X_1,...,X_k).$*

*Verify that: $$\tag{1}E\left[(Y_1-f(x))^2\right] \leq E\left[(Y_2-Y_1)^2\right]  $$*
*and deduce that for every $y \in \text{supp} P_{X_1}:=\{u,\forall r>0,P_{X_1}([y-r,y+r])>0\},f(x+y)=f(x).$*

One way to prove the first question is to note that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x+y)-f(x))^2dP_{X_1}(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x+y+u)-f(x+u))dP_{X_2}(u)\right)^2dP_{X_1}(y) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x+y+u)-f(x+u))^2dP_{X_2}(u)\right)dP_{X_1}(y) \leq E[(Y_2-Y_1)^2]$$
For part 2 we can deduce that for $P_{X_1}$-almost every $y \in \mathbb{R},f(x+y)=f(x),$ how to conclude using continuity that $f(x+y)=f(x)$ for every $y \in \text{supp}P_{X_1}$ ?

How to deduce part 2 ?

Comment: Sorry, I get lost when $E[(Y_2-Y_1)^2]=E[Y_2^2]-E[Y_1^2]$... since $(Y_2-Y_1)^2=Y_2^2 +Y_1^2-2Y_1Y_2$, applying the linearity of expected value will led to $E[(Y_2-Y_1)^2]=E[Y_2^2]+E[Y_2^2]-2E[Y_1Y_2]$, and if $Y_1,\,Y_2$ are independent then $E[Y_1Y_2] = 0$ so $E[(Y_2-Y_1)^2]=E[Y_2^2]+E[Y_1^2]$, with a different sign of what you are using: ¿There is a reason for it being negative?¿or is a typo?

Comment: $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ aren't independent

Comment: If what you state is right: $E[(Y_2-Y_1)^2]=E[Y_2^2]-E[Y_1^2]$, and $Y_1,\,Y_2$ are not independent, since what I state before is always true $E[(Y_2-Y_1)^2]=E[Y_2^2]+E[Y_1^2]-2E[Y_2Y_1]$, using the first equality into the second will lead to $E[Y_2^2]-E[Y_1^2]=E[Y_2^2]+E[Y_1^2]-2E[Y_2Y_1] \iff E[Y_2Y_1]=E[Y_1^2]$ , Doesn´t this will telling that $E[Y_2Y_1]$ is independent of $Y_2$ contradicting that $Y_1,\,Y_2$ are dependent?

Comment: Also, since $E[x^2] \geq 0$ always, if the inequalities is right $E[(Y_2-Y_1)^2] = E[Y_2^2]-E[Y_1^2] \geq 0 \Rightarrow E[Y_2^2] \geq E[Y_1^2]$, Is this consistent with the definition of Y_k?

Comment: Sorry about these questions, but it looks to me very suspicious that the expected value of a squared number ends in being a subtraction: thinking about $X_k$ being i.i.d. with mean $\mu$, the step $E[(Y_1-f(x))^2]=E[Y_1^2]-f(x)^2 = E[f(x+X_1)^2] - f(x)^2\geq 0$ must holds for any arbitrary $\mu >0$ or $\mu<0$, so it kind of saying that $f(x)=\texttt{C}$ a constant function, so the thing you are trying to verify $E[(Y_1-f(x))^2] \leq E[(Y_2-Y_1)^2]$ is just $0\leq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already found that $f(x+y)=f(x)$ for $P_{X_1}$-a.e. $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Now, let $y\in\mathrm{supp}P_{X_1}$. Then $P_{X_1}(y-1/n,y+1/n)>0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, there must exist $y_n\in(y-1/n,y+1/n)$ such that $f(x+y_n)=f(x)$. Obviously $y_n\to y$ and since $f$ is continuous we have
$$
f(x+y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x+y_n)=f(x).
$$