# Mean value property for harmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, harmonic-functions

Consider a bounded harmonic function $u:\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $u$ is a $C^2$ function such that the Laplacian $\Delta u=0$).

Prove, without using Liouville's theorem, the following version of the mean value property:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^p,\; u(x)=\frac{1}{2^p}\int\limits_{[-1,1]^p}u(y+x)dy$$

How can we prove it?

Comment: Maybe mimick the proof of the mean value property for balls that uses the divergence theorem to show that the average of $u$ over a ball of radius $r$ is independent of $r$ by taking the derivative with respect to $r$. Here you would have cubes of side length $r$ instead.

Comment: @Mason I've tried your suggestion and came up with the following: It suffices to show that $\frac{1}{2^p}\int_{[-1,1]^p}y\cdot\nabla u(x+ry)\mathrm{d}y=0$ (this is the derivative with respect to $r$ that you mentioned). Currently, I've no idea, how this can be achieved. I've also tried to first integrate over the boundary of $[-1,1]^p$ (that's the way it is done in Evans' book), but that didn't work either because $y$ is not anymore the unit normal in this case and hence the divergence theorem can't be applied.

Comment: On a side note, I'm wondering if it is really a necessary condition that $u$ is bounded. If it is, then the mean value property in the post is all but useless in view of Liouville's theorem, since it only applies to constant functions. I know you asked about proving the statement without Liouville's theorem, but still. Maybe some more information on where this problem appeared could prove helpful.

Comment: @msgas Yes you are right, apparently (https://www.scirp.org/html/4-5300955_59617.htm), the mean value property only holds for balls, and not any other kind of set. So the solution to this problem might just be to reprove Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe no proof of this statement will be shorter than the following classical proof of a strong form of Liouville's theorem. (This proof is well known, but should be even better known.) Given a bounded function, adding a constant yields a positive function, so the next statement implies that bounded harmonic functions on ${\mathbb R}^d$ are constant.   Let $B_R(x)$ be the ball of radius
$R$ around $x$ in ${\mathbb R}^d$, and let $|B_R|=R^d |B_1|$ be its volume.

**Claim:** If $u:{\mathbb R}^d \to [0,\infty)$ is harmonic, then it is constant.

**Proof:**  Given $x,y \in {\mathbb R}^d$ with $|x-y|=\delta$, we have
$$u(x)=\frac{1}{|B_R|} \int_{B_R(x)} u \,dz \le
 \frac{1}{|B_R|} \int_{B_{R+\delta}(y)} u \,dz =  \frac{|B_{R+\delta}|}{|B_R|} u(y) \,.$$
Taking  $R \to \infty$ yields $u(x) \le u(y)$. The same argument also gives $u(y) \le u(x)$.

Comment: I am searching for a probabilistic proof of Liouville's theorem for bounded harmonic functions and this is possible using Brownian motion, more details can be found in Problem 14 from http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rb812/teaching/sc2019/example2.pdf or exercise 2 (in french) from http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/mickael.maazoun/ens/mb/2019/partiel.pdf (solution in http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/mickael.maazoun/ens/mb/2019/partielcorrige.pdf). Do you think this probabilistic proof works for nonnegative harmonic functions without using the mean value property (or could be deduced from the bounded case) ?

Comment: I think another way (not different from using Brownian motion) is to use Choquet-Deny theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4282680/ey-1-fx2-leq-ey-2-y-12 by considering a sequence $(X_k)_k$ of i.i.d. with the multivariate normal distribution $N(0,I_p).$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand how this answers to the question. Could you develop a bit more pls?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to avoid Liouville completely. At most we can disguise it's proof to give a direct argument. This is what I do.

By translation invariance, we only need to prove this for $x=0$.

Call $C_r u$ the average on cubes, i.e.
$$
C_ru:= (2r)^{-p} \int_{[-r,r]^p} u(y)\, dy.
$$

If $|u(x)|\leq M$, then $|\nabla u(x)|\leq c(p)M$ (this follows from the usual estimates for harmonic functions). With this and the mean value theorem you can bound
$$
|u(0)-C_ru|\leq c(p)Mr.
$$
Set $H_M$ to be the set of harmonic functions bounded by $M$. Then the above says that for any $\varepsilon>0$ and $u\in H_M$ we have
$$
|u(0)-C_{\varepsilon/c(p)M} u|\leq \varepsilon.
$$
Notice that the scaling transformation $u_r(x)=u(x/r)$ leaves the set $H_M$ invariant for any $r>0$, and so we get, for any $u\in H_M$,
$$
|u(0)-C_1u|\leq \varepsilon.
$$
Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary the result follows.

This works with $C_r$ replaced by any nice enough averaging operator. The point is that the translation and scale invariance of $H_M$ is way too good to be true; only constant functions will be there (e.g. a common proof of Liouville exploits this at the level of the gradient estimate $|\nabla u(x)|\leq c(p)M$, where instead we get $|\nabla u(x)|\leq c(p)M/r$ for any $r>0$). So even though we "avoided" Liouville, the basic principle behind it is very much the key to getting the formula.